# Pipes - WaitNamedPipes examples are confusing (MSDN and others)

Tags: named-pipes

Can someone explain WaitNamedPipe for me? Using the examples on MSDN and elsewhere it doesn't seem to be as suggested. Using it in a different order does work.

In the examples, the client does

```
CreateFile (Pipe)
WaitNamedPipe
WriteFile
(Flushbuffers, CloseHandle)
```

Now for me, WaitNamedFile always times out unless I

```
WaitNamedFile
CreateFile
WriteFile
(Flushbuffers, CloseHandle)
```

Server -

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT(HELPPIPE),
        PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        PIPEBUFFERSIZE,
        PIPEBUFFERSIZE,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);
```

and

```
while (!g_Quit)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL))   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
        {
            char buffer[PIPEBUFFERSIZE];
            DWORD dwRead;

            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL))
            {
                // add terminating zero
                buffer[dwRead] = '\0';

                if (!processHelpCommand(buffer))
                {
                    g_Quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    }
```

Client -

```
 if (WaitNamedPipe (TEXT(HELPPIPE), 2000))
{
    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT(HELPPIPE), 
        GENERIC_WRITE, 
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (WriteFile(hPipe,
                    commandLine,
                    strlen (commandLine) + 1,
                    &dwWritten,
                    NULL))
        {
            success = TRUE;
        }
    }

    FlushFileBuffers(hPipe); 
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
}
```

The MSDN example is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipe-client)

A few other on stackoverflow and elsewhere

Comment: The first paragraph on the page you linked says to use `WaitNamedPipe()` if `CreateFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. You only need it if you want to wait for the pipe to become available.

Answer (score 0):

Or is it that I've misunderstood the MSDN exmaple ;-)

I think I've answered my own question.